# how to find out my current user id in other page controller after i login?

Tags: cakephp

i am planing to set a permission on my event index page, which just allow certain user to view which had set when i add the event. After user click into my event, the event controller will 1st check the user id and check the event database which control the user can see which event in his calendar. The permission is added when user create a event and share to other user. Beside, how can i find the current user id to compare with my event database which is the accurate 1?

any suggestion for me to did this function?
i need to know the code and concept how i get the current user id to compare with all the event database, and allow the current user see the certain event.

thanks alot for your information.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The recommended approach for getting logged in user data is via the AuthComponent itself:

```
// in any controller
$userId = $this->Auth->user('id');
```

See [Accessing the logged in user](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#accessing-the-logged-in-user) in the Auth section of the [CakePHP Book](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/index.html).

Answer (score 6):

Use sessions to save and read data for a user between pages.

**Within Controllers:**

```
// store a user id in the session
$this->Session->write('User.id', $userId);

// read a user id from the session
$userId = $this->Session->read('User.id');
```

**Within Views:**

```
// read a user id from the session
$userId = $session->read('User.id');
```

You can use any key you want if you prefer something over "User.id".  I simply use this since it is what the `AuthComponent` defaults to if you are using that.

Comment: +1 for thorough example, but "The major difference between the Session Helper and the Session Component is that the helper does not have the ability to write to the session." http://book.cakephp.org/view/484/Session

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that difference, I updated my response to reflect that.

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for are ACLs (Access Control Lists). There's an [`AclComponent`](http://book.cakephp.org/view/171/Access-Control-Lists) built into Cake which you should look into. It works together with the [`AuthComponent`](http://book.cakephp.org/view/172/Authentication), which will hold the user id. It's a little complicated at first, but worth the hassle.

Comment: AclComponent only happens to be used under the hood in some *authorization* modules. AuthComponent is where to look for the *authenticated* user, as well as other top level auth related things.

Answer (score 1):

Also, for a simple approach, have a look at the `model` and `controller` settings of [`AuthComponent::authorize`](http://book.cakephp.org/view/248/AuthComponent-Variables#authorize-396). This allows you to define an `isAuthorized()` method in your controller or model (your choice) which will store logic that determines access (should return `true` if access allowed and `false` if denied).

Answer (score 0):

to see sessions, queries, data, and everything else that is passed from page to page in cake use this amazing little helper http://thechaw.com/debug_kit