# Setting a Session using Nice Auth (CakePHP plugin) and accessing Session information.

Tags: php, session, cakephp, authentication

I am having issues accessing session information upon login.  I am using Nice Auth a plugin for CakePHP.

I have followed some instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1706016/how-to-find-out-my-current-user-id-in-other-page-controller-after-i-login)

What I am trying to do is access the users username so that on another page they do not need to fill out who they are when they send a support ticket.

This is the Userscontroller login function:

```
public function login(){
        if ($this->request->is('post') || ($this->request->is('get') && isset($this->request->query['openid_mode']))) {
            if ($this->Auth->login()) {
                $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
                }
            else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));
                }
            }
        }
```

Which is where I would assume I put the

```
$this->Session->write('User.id', $userId);
```

Below is the tickets controller:

```
public function send()
    {
        $userId = $this->Auth->user();
        if ( !empty($this->request->data) )
        {
            $email = new CakeEmail();
            $email->from(array('xxxx@example.com'))
                //->to($this->request->data['to'])
                ->to(array('helpdesk@example.com'))
                ->subject($this->request->data['subject']);

            if ($email->send($this->request->data['message']))
            {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Email Sent Successfully'),
                    'default', array('class' => 'success'));
            }
        }

    }
```

Where I would expect to put this code:

```
$userId = $this->Session->read('User.id');
```

And then to display in my View:

```
$userId = $session->read('User.id');
```

Now, I have added the Session Component and Helpers to the files as I thought that would be what was causing me issues, but No dice!

Any help is greatly appreciated.

My Current error messages look like this:

```
Notice (8): Undefined variable: session [APP/View/Tickets/send.ctp, line 10] Fatal error: Call to a member function read() on a non-object in /Users/bellis/workspace/cake/app/View/Tickets/send.ctp on line 10
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, the recommended method is to do it like this:

```
$userId = $this->Auth->user('id');
```

You can access the logged in user via that method from any controller.

Answer (score 1):

```
    set session in your $helpers array in your controller or app controller

    var $helpers=array('Session'); 

   if you have use cake 1.2 ver use above code and if you have use higher ver  like 2.0, 2.1 etc use below code

public $helpers = array('Session');




    your can set variable in controller

        $userId = $this->Session->read('User.id');

        $this->set('userid', userId );


        and directly access $userid variable in your ctp file


        OR

        You can directly access

        $userId = $this->Session->read('User.id');

        in your ctp file
```

Answer (score 0):

Include Session helper in your controller using:

```
 public $helpers = array('Session',.........);
```

and try to use following in your view:

```
$userId = $this->Session->read('User.id');
```

Kindly ask if it not worked for you.